# How to download Email by ID?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to do **lazy downloading email**. Basically the problem is that my emails are heavy. So I'm downloading only subject and message-id and only when it's needed I'm downloading rest of email.

The first step is to download subject and message-id:

```
public void downloadInBackground(EmailAccount emailAccount, String folderName) {
    List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();
    Message[] message = null;

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    Store store = null;
    Folder folder = null;
    try {
        Log.getInstance().d("xxx", "starting dowanloading");
        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(emailAccount.getImapServer(), emailAccount.getUsername(),
                emailAccount.getPassword());

        folder = store.getFolder(folderName);
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        message = folder.getMessages();
        FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
        fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        fp.add("Subject"); fp.add("From"); fp.add("To"); fp.add("Cc"); fp.add("Bcc"); fp.add("ReplyTo"); fp.add("Date");
        folder.fetch(message, fp);

        for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
            Message m = message[i];

            String emailId = null;

            m.getHeader("Message-Id");
            Enumeration<Header> headers = m.getAllHeaders();
            while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
                Header h = headers.nextElement();
                String mID = h.getName();
                if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(mID, "Message-ID")) {
                    emailId = h.getValue();
                }
            }

            if (emailId != null) {
                Email newMail = new LazyEmail(m, emailAccount, folderName, emailId);
                emails.add(newMail);
            }
        }
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        ...
    } finally {
        if (folder != null) {
                folder.close(false);
        }
        if (store != null) {
                store.close();
        }
    }

    update(emails);
}
```

Next in LazyEmail, when it's needed. I'm downloading rest of email:

```
public void updateContentText() {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    Store store = null;
    Folder folder = null;
    try {
        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(mEmailAccount.getImapServer(), mEmailAccount.getUsername(),
                mEmailAccount.getPassword());

        folder = store.getFolder(mFolderName);
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // finding email
        SearchTerm searchTerm = new MessageIDTerm(mEmailId);
        Message[] messages = folder.search(searchTerm);
        assert messages.length == 1;

        // setting context text
        Part mail = messages[0];
        if (mail.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
            setContentText((Multipart) mail.getContent());
        } else {
            setContentText((String) mail.getContent());
        }

        updateState = UpdateState.CONTENT_TEXT_DOWNLOADED;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    } finally {
        if (folder != null) {
                folder.close(false);
        }
        if (store != null) {
                store.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Code seems looks ok. But when I'm running my Android application I gets error in line Message[] messages = folder.search(searchTerm);

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: A4 BAD Execute(): Error in command received;
```

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using and what does the [JavaMail protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Note also that fetching all those headers in addition to the envelope is pretty much a waste.  Unless you're accessing the raw headers directly JavaMail is going to get all that information from the envelope.

Finally, the way you're using it, there's no reason to set the "mail.store.protocol" property.  And see [these common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).